# Isbn generate the check digit

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

This code verifies whether an ISBN is valid. For nine-digit inputs, I'd like to form a valid ISBN by calculating and appending the check digit. For inputs less than nine digits, I'd like it to return the error message "Please enter a correct number". How should I go about this?

```
   public class isbn
    {   //attributes
         private string isbnNum;
         //method   
         public string GetIsbn()
         {
             return this.isbnNum;
         }
           //constructor
           public isbn()
           {
               Console.Write("Enter Your ISBN Number: ");
               this.isbnNum = Console.ReadLine();

           }//end default constructor

            //method
           public string displayISBN()
           {

               return  this.GetIsbn();

           }


       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create a new instance of the ISBN/book class

            isbn myFavoriteBook = new isbn();

            //contains the method for checking validity 
            bool isValid = CheckDigit.CheckIsbn(myFavoriteBook.GetIsbn());

            //print out the results of the validity.
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Your book {0} a valid ISBN",
                                       isValid ? "has" : "doesn't have"));

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

public static class CheckDigit
{       // attributes
    public static string NormalizeIsbn(string isbn)
    {
        return isbn.Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "");
    }
   public static bool CheckIsbn(string isbn) // formula to check ISBN's validity
    {
        if (isbn == null)
            return false;

        isbn = NormalizeIsbn (isbn);
        if (isbn.Length != 10)
            return false;

        int result;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            if (!int.TryParse(isbn[i].ToString(), out result))
                return false;

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            sum += (i + 1) * int.Parse(isbn[i].ToString());

        int remainder = sum % 11;
        if (remainder == 10)
            return isbn[9] == 'X';
        else
            return isbn[9] == (char)('0' + remainder);
    }
```

Comment: Nope it is an exercise from a book

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change it to append the last character rather than checking that it's present. The above could be cleaned up a bit, but just changing it as required results in:

```
public static string MakeIsbn(string isbn) // string must have 9 digits
{
    if (isbn == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    isbn = NormalizeIsbn (isbn);
    if (isbn.Length != 9)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    int result;
    for (int i = 0; i != 9; i++)
        if (!int.TryParse(isbn[i].ToString(), out result))
            throw new ArgumentException()

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != 9; i++)
        sum += (i + 1) * int.Parse(isbn[i].ToString());

    int remainder = sum % 11;
    if (remainder == 10)
        return isbn + 'X';
    else
        return isbn + (char)('0' + remainder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreciate it but the program has to be able to do both. Because the final part is to add a form on top of the console and make it have 2 buttons one that verifies and one that generates.

Comment: @Michael. That's why the above is a separate method with a new name, that you can add to the class in question. It would be possible to refactor to remove the duplication, but start by working out why the two you have work first.